# How to save a multer image array

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[here my code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2MUn.png)

As shown in the picture, the code is the same. I try to upload an image to the seqeulize db with multer, but I can't distinguish it. Can't save the image as an array?

Comment: please paste your code here.

Comment: router.post('/WIPICK_POST_PHOTOWITH_CONTENT', upload.array('image',5), async (req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.body, req.file);
    console.log('test',req.hostname);
    var Data = [];
    for(var i=0; i<req.files.length; i++){
        var OrigianlData = {
            img : req.files[i].filename,
        };
        Data.push(OrigianlData);
        

    }try {
        Post.bulkCreate(Data, {
            returning : true
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
    }

    res.json({url : `/photo/${req.files.filename}`});
});

Comment: Edit your question paste the code into the question itself, not in the comment.